# Form not saving object a redirect to new form view

Tags: python, django, forms

I am attempting to build an app the creates patient data, saves it, and displays it.

Problem : When I populate the fields and click save it does not save the object and render data to the document object model. It reloads the page with the field data still in the fields.

I am not sure what I have done wrong. The view, form and models code seem to be accurate. I welcome any **useful** assistance.

> Here is the code :

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from Identity import settings
import datetime


class Identity_unique(models.Model):

    NIS = models.CharField(max_length = 200, primary_key = True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    Timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    first_Name = models.CharField(max_length = 80, null = True )
    last_Name = models.CharField(max_length = 80, null = True )
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = False, blank = True, null = True)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length = 15, null = True)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, UpdateView
from nesting.forms import Identity_Form, Symptom_Form
from nesting.models import Identity_unique, Symptom_relation


class Identity_view(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'nesting/nesting.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = Identity_Form()
        Identities = Identity_unique.objects.filter(user = request.user)
        var = {'form': form, 'Identities': Identities}
        return render(request, self.template_name, var)

    def post(self, request):
        form  = Identity_Form(request.POST or None)
        content = None
        if form.is_valid():
            NIS = form.save(commit = False)
            NIS.user = request.user
            NIS.save()

            content = form.cleaned_data['NIS']
            form = Identity_Form()
            return redirect('nesting:nesting')

        var = {'form': form, 'content': content}
        return render(request,self.template_name, var)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from nesting.models import Identity_unique
from nesting.models import Symptom_relation


class Identity_Form(forms.ModelForm):

    NIS = forms.CharField(
                    widget=forms.TextInput(
                            attrs={

                                'placeholder': 'Enter NIS',
                                'class' : 'form-control'
                            }
                )
    )

    first_Name = forms.CharField(
                widget=forms.TextInput(
                        attrs={

                            'placeholder': 'Enter First Name',
                            'class' : 'form-control'
                        }
            )
    )
    last_Name = forms.CharField(

       widget=forms.TextInput(
               attrs={

                   'placeholder': 'Enter Last Name',
                   'class' : 'form-control'
               }
        )
    )

    location = forms.CharField(

            widget=forms.TextInput(
                        attrs= {

                        'placeholder':'Enter Address',
                        'class':'form-control'

                        }
            )
    )

    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(

            required = False,
                widget=forms.TextInput(
                            attrs= {

                            'placeholder' : 'Enter Birthday',
                            'class':'form-control'

                            }
                ),
        )

    contact = forms.CharField(

                    widget=forms.TextInput(
                                attrs= {

                                'placeholder':'Enter Contact',
                                'class':'form-control'

                                }
                    )
            )


    class Meta:

        model = Identity_unique

        fields = ('NIS', 'first_Name', 'last_Name', 'location', 'date_of_birth', 'contact',)
```

***Edit***

**nesting.html**

```
<form method = 'post' novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
          {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    <div class = "form-row">
        <div class = "form-group col-md-6">
        {{ form.NIS.errors }}
        {{ form.NIS }}
        </div>

        <div class = "form-group col-md-6">
        {{form.Contact.errors}}
        {{form.Contact}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "form-row">
        <div class = "form-group col-md-6">
        {{form.first_Name.errors}}
        {{form.first_Name}}
        </div>

        <div class = "form-group col-md-6">
        {{form.last_Name.errors}}
        {{form.last_Name}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "form-row">
        <div class = "form-group col-md-6">
        {{form.location.errors}}
        {{form.location}}
        </div>

        <div class = "form-group col-md-6">
        {{form.date_of_birth.errors}}
        {{form.date_of_birth}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class = "btn-primary btn-large btn ">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: print `form.errors` in the view or `{{ form.errors}}` in the template to see why the form isn't valid. The problem could be in your template, which you haven't shown.

Comment: @Alasdair I added the templates to the problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

The fields that you are rendering in your template do not match the fields in the form - so the form will fail to validate. Specifically, your form has a `contact` field, which you are trying to render in the template with `form.Contact`.

Case matters - `contact` is not the same as `Contact`, and as it is currently your `contact` field will not get rendered at all. `form.errors` will contain an error message highlighting this issue.

Your use of capitals in field names is quite inconsistent, which makes it easy to make mistakes like this. Convention in Django is for field names to be lower cased.